# MySQL join where occurs more than once in initial table

Tags: mysql

I'm using the following query to join two tables successfully.  I'd like to add criteria that only displays agents that have at least 2 records where SearchPrice >= 250000 ...I tried adding "HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2" but when I add this I only get one result?  I think it is applying the "HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2" to the ActiveAgent table maybe?

```
    SELECT 
    r.EmailAddress AS ag_email, 
    e.ListingAgentFullName AS ag_name, 
    r.OfficeName AS ag_office_name 
    FROM RESI 
    e JOIN ActiveAgent r 
    ON e.ListingAgentNumber=r.MemberNumber
    WHERE SearchPrice >= 250000;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
SELECT 
    r.EmailAddress AS ag_email, 
    COUNT(r.EmailAddress) AS `acount`,
    e.ListingAgentFullName AS ag_name, 
    r.OfficeName AS ag_office_name 
    FROM RESI 
    e LEFT JOIN ActiveAgent r 
    ON e.ListingAgentNumber=r.MemberNumber
    WHERE SearchPrice >= 250000;
    GROUP BY r.EmailAddress
    HAVING acount >=2
```